# jqgrid date picker produces firebug error

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to do a very simple example of datepicker field.

```
{ name: 'p_ManagerDateApproved', width: 80, editable: true, editoptions: { dataInit: function(el) { setTimeout(function() { $(el).datepicker(); }, 200); } } },
```

Firebug says "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

...Init: function(el) { setTimeout(function() { $(el).datepicker(); }, 200); } } }

Everything else in my grid seems to work ok.  Can anyone give me an idea of how to go about solving this, I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Do you included jQuer UI JavaScript file like `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js` for example?

Comment: Yes but, now that you mention it, I bet that particular line does not make it through my company proxy server !  I think I will have to download that library to my server.

Comment: Ok, in Firebug it seems to load the ajax file fine from google.      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt able to post this in a comment so here is my code I probably should have posted this first sorry

```
    <head>
<style>
#gbox_grid{display:none;}
a:link {color:blue;}
a:visited {color:blue;}
a:hover {color:blue;}
a:active {color:yellow;}
.readonly {background-color: WhiteSmoke !important;}
</style>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>jQgrid - ASPX</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <!--<script src="http://asp2d:1138/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="http://asp2d:1138/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://asp2d:1138/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://asp2d:1138/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://asp2d:1138/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://asp2d:1138/ui.jqgrid.css" />
  <script>
    $(function () {
```